# How to access keys inside api objects

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

I'm trying to get the countries inside a select option from the API 
https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries.

github link : https://github.com/nitink66/corona-updates

It used to work like past two days but now i'm just getting the numbers inside the select option instead of the countries.
How should I access the countries so that I can display it on the select option tag.

```
  const respCountries = await Axios.get("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
  const countries = Object.keys(respCountries.data.countries);
  this.setState({
    confirmed: respApi.data.confirmed.value,
    recovered: respApi.data.recovered.value,
    deaths: respApi.data.deaths.value,
    countries
  });
}

renderCountryOptions(){
  return this.state.countries.map((country,i)=>{
      return <option key={i}>{country}</option>
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `Object.keys`, its unnecessary and your update state for countries is not correct

```
const countries = respCountries.data.countries;

this.setState({
    confirmed: respApi.data.confirmed.value,
    recovered: respApi.data.recovered.value,
    deaths: respApi.data.deaths.value,
    countries: countries,
  });

renderCountryOptions(){
  return this.state.countries.map((country,i)=>{
      return <option key={i}>{country.name}</option>
  });
}
```

Comment: It throws an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: its work correctly here https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-monad-w44cy

Comment: i found your setState for country is not correct, i updated answer, you can try again @Nitin

Answer (score 0):

{country.name} the countries is now an object with other attributes.